# "Pickle" in python raises errors in my code:

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle, eof

I am new to python and am trying to teach myself how to program in python through the us of codecademy. But in my own time I decided to attempt to program a phone book using dictionaries and the pickle function i read about on this forum. But in experimenting with pickle to save my dictionary for the phone book itself the code kept raising an "EOFError" I have no idea what this is or how to solve it. So, if anyone is able to help me i would really appreciate it

```
#My Code

import pickle

PhoneBook = {}
reloaded = {}

with open("C:\\Programming\\Phone Book.txt", "rb") as inf:  #Modify this dependent on         where the file is located
    reloaded = pickle.load(inf)

def help():
    print "add_contact('name', 'number') - Adds a new contact to your phone book."
    print "display_phone_book() - Displays the contents of your phone book."
    print "display_contact('name') - Displays the resident of your phone book with the corrosponding name."

def add_contact(name, number):
    PhoneBook [name] = number
    with open("C:\\Programming\\Phone Book.txt", "wb") as outf:  #Modify this dependent on where the file is located
        pikle.dump(PhoneBook, outf)

def display_phone_book():
    print PhoneBook

def display_contact(name):
    print "%s's phone number is:" %(name)
    print PhoneBook[name]

#Error's Code:
def load_eof(self):
    raise EOFError
dispatch[''] = load_eof
```

Comment: Post the error please.

Comment: Also, please post real code; this code is going to raise a `NameError` on that `pikle.dump`, or at least it would if you actually called any of these functions. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `pikle.dump(PhoneBook, outf)` definitely won't work. What is the last function supposed to be doing? I'm very confused. Looks like you'd be setting the value of a key `''` in the dictionary `dispatch` equal to a function? Except you have no such dictionary, and none of your functions get called.

Comment: But as a quick guess: If you're unconditionally trying to load `PhoneBook.txt`, even the very first time you run the program, when you've never _saved_ anything there yet, that's obviously not going to work. To fix that, you probably want a `try`/`except` that does some useful default behavior (maybe nothing) if the file is missing or empty.

Comment: Completely forgot I posted this a year pack as I didn't receive emails for your comments. Sorry about that. In this past year I've become a lot more experienced in python but I am still extremely thankful for your comments it would have helped massively at the time. Again thanks for the help and I'm outstandingly sorry for my rudeness this past year as even though I hadn't recieved an email I should have still checked this post. Again so sorry for this.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without seeing the actual code that demonstrates the problem, or the error, or how you're using it, but…

The first time you run your program, there's nothing in `PhoneBook.txt`. Either the `open` or the `pickle.load` is going to fail. And since you can't even get past the first few lines of the first run of the program, there's no way the problem will ever get fixed; you'll just keep getting the same failure forever.

If that's your problem, you probably want something like this:

```
try:
    with open("C:\\Programming\\Phone Book.txt", "rb") as inf:
        reloaded = pickle.load(inf)
except (IOError, EOFError) as e:
    print('Failed to find old data ({!r}), creating new'.format(e))
    reloaded = {}
```

You might want to restrict the cases that are automatically handled a bit (e.g., on IOError, if it's `EACCES` instead of `ENOENT`, don't try to just ignore the error and move on) or expand them (e.g., if the file isn't empty, but is corrupted, you might get a `KeyError` instead of an `EOFError`). If you're not sure what you want, it may be best to start with `except Exception as e:`, come up with a bunch of test cases, see what you get for each one, and decide which ones should make the program fail and which ones should be handled by just starting from scratch.

Comment: Completely forgot I posted this a year pack as I didn't receive emails for your comments. Sorry about that. In this past year I've become a lot more experienced in python but I am still extremely thankful for your comments it would have helped massively at the time. Again thanks for the help and I'm outstandingly sorry for my rudeness this past year as even though I hadn't recieved an email I should have still checked this post. Again so sorry for this.